# Android Minimum SDKs and Color Schemes

Tags: java, android

So I've built an application that uses a certain default color scheme in API 15. However, I am aware that most devices are still running API 10. In order to appeal to these devices, I switched the minimum SDK on my device to 10. After doing this, I noticed that the default grayish-black color of my buttons now became white on the older devices - I suspect this is because that particular color was not available in API 10. My question is thus as follows: Is there anyway to package this resource into my APK file in order to allow these devices to see the color as I intended it, or do I need to re-design?

Comment: Changing the minimumSdk shouldn't affect any of that unless you're on a device (or emulator) at that lower SDK level. Are you leaving the targetSdk at 15?

Comment: The whole point is to make it look nice on the devices running the lower SDK levels though.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that the problem is that it displays differently on older devices. I'll post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use resources that aren't available in older versions, you can easily go grab them out of the `platforms` folder of your SDK and copy them into your app locally. Alternately, you can define a fallback style (and just manually code the theme yourself instead of using android styles) by placing your old device-compatible theme in `res/values/styles.xml` and placing the newer device-compatible version of the theme in `res/values-v11/styles.xml` (replacing v11 with whatever version your resource became available -- typically v11 is the major change).

EDIT: Per your below comment, just make another `themes.xml` file under `res/values`, and copy that style into it, changing the parent to `@android:style/Theme` instead of `Theme.Holo`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit new to dealing with themes. All I really want to do is change the color of the text on the buttons in the older device cases and keep the Holo theme in the case of all newer devices. Could you give me some short examples of the XML I would have to put into each of those folders to do this?

Comment: What are you currently doing to set the style?

Comment: Inside my values-v11 folder I have a file called themes.xml. The only code I have in here is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    </style>
</resources>. I am not sure how to proceed with the older devices.

Comment: I have a follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167063/android-styles-for-api-10-and-api-11 if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an API level 15 theme everywhere, I **strongly** suggest you look at the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) project.

This allows your app to use the same type of theme and buttons regardless of API level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which certain default color scheme you're referring to, but [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) has been pretty useful for me to use the various Holo themes in android 2.1 and up.